# Write the equation that gives you your velocity away from planet X.

Tags: trigonometry

Earlier, I posed the following problem:

> Suppose you are travelling through a planetary system. From your space ship you view planet X. The planet is known to be spherical. As you view planet X, the angle $A$ from the centre of the planet to the outer edge of the planet is 3 degrees. The distance $d$ from your space ship to the nearest surface of the planet is 100,000 miles. What is the exact radius $r$ of the planet to the nearest tenth of a mile?

First you wrote: $$\sin A = \frac r{r+d}$$
You then solved for the radius r and obtained:  $$r = \frac{d\sin A}{1-\sin A}$$
You then correctly computed 5,522.6 miles as the radius of planet X.

Immediately after the initial readings, something went terribly wrong.  Your rockets misfired for several seconds.  This caused your space ship to travel directly away from planet X.  Due to equipment failures, you can no longer get distance readings, but you can still read the instrument that was used to measure angle $A$.  Now, 5 hours after the mishap, you read angle $B$ as 2 degrees.

Write an equation that gives $V$, the average velocity (away from planet X) during the period since the mishap occurred.  The equation will be in terms of $r$, the radius of planet X (in miles), the time $t$ (in hours) that has elapsed since the initial readings, and angles $A$ and $B$.  As a check, your equation should tell you that $V$ is 10,544 miles per hour.  I will show a nice equation in about four hours if no one else does.  This is not homework.  This is just an opportunity to demonstrate the power of maths and trigonometry, and for you to show off your maths ability and earn a few points.

...

Since no one responded, and 4 hours have passed, here is the equation as promised:
$$V = \frac {r*(sin(A)-sin(B))}{t*sin(A)*sin(B)}$$

The values to use are:$$r = 5522.6, t = 5, A = 3, B = 2$$

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to know the value of $r$ to obtain a formula giving  the velocity.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative formula that does not require to use the numerical value of $r$ can be obtained as follows. Since $r$ does not change, we can write $$\frac{d \sin(A)}{(1-\sin(A))}=\frac{(d+xt) \sin(B)}{(1-\sin(B))}$$

where $d$ is the initial distance, $t$ is time and $x$ is the average velocity. We then get

$$ x= \frac{1}{t} [d \frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(B)} \frac {(1-\sin(B)}{(1-\sin(A))}-d]$$

which leads to

$$ x= \frac{1}{5} [100000 \frac{\sin(3)}{\sin(2)} \frac {(1-\sin(2)}{(1-\sin(3))}-100000]=20000 \frac{\sin(3)-\sin(2)}{\sin(2)-\sin(2) \sin(3)}= 10544$$

Comment: I'm happy to see this alternative solution.  Nice work Anatoly.